# Prove that every signed measure $\mu$ has a decomposition into difference $\mu=\mu^+ - \mu^-$ , where $\mu^+ , \mu^-$ are measures .

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Every signed measure $\mu$ on $(X,M)$ has a decomposition into difference $\mu=\mu^+ - \mu^-$ , where $\mu^+ , \mu^-$ are measures . (Here $-\infty \lt \mu(E)\le \infty$ for every measurable set $E\in M$ )

I have see Hahn decomposition theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem) . But in Stein & Shakarchi's real analysis Page $_{288}$, it proves this conclusion in another way .

> Let $|\mu|$ denote the total variation of $\mu$ , by $$|\mu|(E)=\sup \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|\mu(E_j)|$$ where the supremum is taken over all partitions of $E$ .
>   Then we can construct the decomposition as follows : $$\mu^+=\frac12 (|\mu|+\mu)$$  $$\mu^-(E)=0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{whenever $\mu(E)=\infty$}$$
>   $$\mu^-(E)=\frac12 (|\mu|-\mu)(E) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \text{whenever $\mu(E) \lt \infty$}$$
>   We can see that $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are measures , and they clearly satisfy $$\mu=\mu^+ - \mu^-$$

I can prove that both $|\mu|$ and $\mu^+$ are measures and $\mu \le |\mu|$ . But I have some trouble when dealing with $\mu^-$ .
My attempt:
Remember a set function $v$ called measure iff it satisfy :
$(1)$ For every measurable set $E \in M$ , $0\le v(E) \le \infty$
$(2)$ If $E_1,E_2,... $ is a countable family of disjoint sets in $M$ , then $$\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)$$

It is easy to see that $\mu^-$ satisfy property $(1)$ . However , if $E_1 , E_2$ denote two disjoint set in $M$ , I can not even prove $\mu^-(E_1 \bigcup E_2) = \mu^-(E_1)+\mu^-(E_2)$ . And I think the example follows might show $\mu^-$ can not be a measure .

Consider the space $R$ with Lebesgue measurable set . Construct a function $f$ : $f(x)=x$ whenever $x\in [-1,\infty)$  and $f(x)=0$ otherwise .
Then we can construct a signed measure $\mu$ by $$\mu(E)=\int_E f(x) \,dx$$ 
Some simple observation may show that $\mu^-$ defined above can not be a measure . If $\mu^-$ is a measure , then $$\mu^-([-1,2]\bigcup (2,\infty))=\mu^-([-1,2])+\mu^-((2,\infty))$$ Since $\mu([-1,\infty)=\mu((2,\infty))=\infty$ , LHS $=0$ while RHS $=\mu^-([-1,2])$ this may lead to a contradiction if we can prove $\mu^-([-1,2])\gt 0$ . By definition of $|\mu|$ , we have $$|\mu|([-1,2]) \ge |\mu([-1,0]|+|\mu((0,2]|=\frac52$$ . Also , we have $\mu([-1,2]=\frac32$ directly , so $$\mu^-([-1,2])\ge \frac12(\frac52-\frac32)=\frac12$$ which leads to a contradication . So $\mu^-$ defined above can not be a measure .
This example made me so confused , since the decomposition defined above is an theorem in my textbook rather than an exercise . So , did I make something wrong in my discussion above ?

Comment: I agree that the definition seems incorrect. Setting $\mu^-(E) = 0$ if $\mu(E)=\infty$ will require $\mu^-(X)=0$ if $\mu(X)=\infty$ (as in your example). Then, since $\mu^-$ is supposed to be an unsigned measure, this would require $\mu^- \equiv 0.$ This is certainly not what we want.

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks for clarifying what the problem is. Someone should explain to S&S that there's a good reason $\infty-\infty$ is called "indeterminate". In fact come to think of it the definition of $\mu^+$ is also problematic if $\mu(E)=-\infty$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. They only allow a signed measure to take positive infinity, not negative infinity, so that problem is avoided.

Comment: @md2perpe Oh. Ok then - imo it would be better to define "signed measure" as usual, since it's a fairly standard term. The standard proof of the Jordan decomposition is not that hard...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. Unfortunately it's a bit too late to contact Stein about this issue; he died in December 2018. I found an errata, but nothing is said there about this: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~jwguo/teaching/real/2016pdf/errata.pdf

Comment: Here's a PDF copy of the book: http://www.cmat.edu.uy/~mordecki/courses/medida2013/book.pdf